# Swift - How do I detect the exact point at which two "SKPhysicsBody(edgeFromPoint:" type physics bodies intersect in sprite kit

Tags: collision-detection, ios

I have two physics bodies attached to two separate sprite nodes using Sprit Kit.  One is a vertical line and one is a horizontal line:

```
//sprite with horizontal physics body
spriteMatrix[i][j].physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeFromPoint: CGPointMake(0, tileSegmentHeight), toPoint: CGPointMake(tileSegmentWidth, tileSegmentHeight))
spriteMatrix[i][j].physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = self.surfaceCatagory
spriteMatrix[i][j].physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = heroCatagory

//sprite with vertical physics body
self.hero.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeFromPoint: CGPointMake(self.hero.frame.width / 2, self.hero.frame.height / 2), toPoint: CGPointMake(self.hero.frame.width / 2, -20))
self.hero.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = heroCatagory
self.hero.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = surfaceCatagory
```

What I'm want to do is test if they are intersecting on every frame, and if they are, return the x and y position of where they are intersecting.  Is this even possible?

Comment: I'd like to add that I plan to implement sloped physics bodies later so being that I we know the x an y positions already isn't going to cut it.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using **collisionBitMask** The class reference can be found [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013032-CH1-SW22)

A example of code is [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31109659/how-does-collisionbitmask-work-swift-spritekit) which also explains very well how collisionBitMask works

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.  Apparently, only a dynamic volume physics body can make contact with an edge body.  I do not like this about Sprite Kit.